# Is this sample good sample to use try catch ? What's sugesstions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, coding-style

Its a paradox for me, can i handle all exception or let it go to find and solve it.

I have a windowservice and it has several methods like this:

Is this bad sample ?

```
  public void BeginOperation() 
  {    
    try
    {
          DoSync();
    }    
    catch (Exception x){
          Log(x.message)
          Show(x.message);   
    }
  }


 public void DoSync() 
   {    
     try
     {
      GetSampleDatatable();
      ApplyDiff();
      CommitDiff();
    }    
    catch (Exception x){
      Log(x.message)
      throw x;  
    }
   }
```

> DataLayer Sample

```
   public DataTable GetSampleDatatable() 
   {    
        OracleDataTable myDataTable;
        try
        {
            myDataTable = new OracleDataTable(sqlStr, this);
            myDataTable.FetchAll = true;
            myDataTable.Active = true;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = x.Message;
            throw x;
        }
        return myDataTable;
    }
```

Comment: You biggest issue here is that you are catching all exceptions all the time with just `catch Exception`. Think hard about which exceptions exactly can happen, and then it will become clear where to catch which (if catch them at all)

Comment: i understand, what is the best handle exceptions for this sample, can u tell about it shortly

Comment: Never use `throw x;` That messes up your stack trace! Just use `throw;`. And here's an important point: only catch an exception *when you can deal with it*. If you can't handle the issue, then don't catch it there. Let it bubble up to something that can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a good practice. There are a few reasons you might catch an exception:

1. You can handle it and make some sort of decision about how to proceed
2. You want to add additional detail to the exception and let it bubble up
3. It doesn't matter if something fails (this is very rare, and you probably want to at least log it)

So your first code block....

```
public void BeginOperation() 
{    
    try
    {
        DoSync();
    }    
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Log(x.message)
        Show(x.message);   
    }
}

public void DoSync() 
{    
    try
    {
        GetSampleDatatable();
        ApplyDiff();
        CommitDiff();
    }    
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Log(x.message);
        throw x;  
    }
}
```

`DoSync` doesn't fall into any of these categories. You're logging the error, but `BeginOperation` logs it as well so now you've got redundant logging. Rewritten, it should be like this:

```
public void BeginOperation() 
{    
    try
    {
        DoSync();
    }    
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Log(x.message);
        Show(x.message);   
    }
}

public void DoSync() 
{    
    GetSampleDatatable();
    ApplyDiff();
    CommitDiff();
}
```

In fact, I question whether `DoSync` is necessary at all, you could simplify this further. But perhaps you have some organizational reason for doing so.

```
public void BeginOperation() 
{    
    try
    {
        GetSampleDatatable();
        ApplyDiff();
        CommitDiff();
    }    
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Log(x.message)
        Show(x.message);   
    }
}
```

Now for the data layer. Again, you've got some issues in here. You're catching an exception, but you can't deal with it here. There was no point in catching it. Simply let the error bubble up to somewhere it can be handled (`BeginOperation`).

```
public DataTable GetSampleDatatable() 
{    
    OracleDataTable myDataTable = new OracleDataTable(sqlStr, this);
    myDataTable.FetchAll = true;
    myDataTable.Active = true;
    return myDataTable;
}
```

Additionally, you're using `throw ex;`. This is not a good pattern. You lose stack trace information and it makes it difficult in your IDE to quickly determine where exception originated. Simply use `throw;` and it will preserve stack trace information. Of course, when you're only catching exceptions for the three reasons I mentioned above, this shouldn't happen too often.

Comment: thanks @mason for ur reply